# Tableau, toggle between graph and crosstab

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data set I have imported and into Tableau and in created a crosstab (by using the "duplicate tab as crosstab" option from the context menu on the worksheet. Is there a way to toggle between crosstab/chart visual with out duplicating the worksheet?

Comment: can you add a dataset example to your question?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the data set, however I have included a link in the answer which points to a example with a data set that you can reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In the marks panel the drop down and measure values need to have the text option specified.

[image: screen shot of marks panel.]

Tableau online help:

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/buildexamples_text.htm

I also found that if I used a measure in the row, I had to change the type from continuous to discrete.

[image: Row measure]

[image: changing the row measure to discrete]